# How to configure Magento 1.8 with TLS1.2?

Tags: magento-1.8, ssl, ups

From somedays in my website UPS rates are not working fine. I found on google that I need to configure my Magento with TSL1.2.

My current Magento version is `1.8`. Can anyone tell me how to configure `Magento 1.8` with `TSL1.2`.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: I solved it by upgrading magento from 1.8 to 1.9